# New ASP.NET MVC project contains membership functionality but no database

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I created ASP.NET MVC 3 project and it has functionality to create users and login/logout.  However I don't see a database that its trying to work with. I assumed that a mdf file would be added to App_Data folder but I don't see it there. When I try to register a user, it cannot find a sql server.

Connection string in web.config has:

```
      <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
         AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have SQL Server express installed on the machine.

Beyond that your other option is to create a database in SQL Server and use the aspnet_regsql tool in the Framework folder to generate the tables needed to back the membership functionality. Once you have done that change your connection string to point to the correct SQL instance and you should be up and running no problem.

Comment: I have SQL Server but not SQL Server Express. Do I really need express running?

Comment: Yes, you do. Your connection string is pointing to a SQL Express instance (see the .\SQLEXPRESS part of the connection string. Further, the ability to create a database on the fly, dump it on that folder and connect to it is dependent on SQL Express. Full SQL does not do the AttachDBFilename thing.

Comment: Ah, I should have caught that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just setup a MVC3 project. If you run the application for the first time, and you click on login, then register a user, the application will create a sql express database in your App_Data folder called ASPNETDB.MDF. I'm pretty sure that you're going to need to have SQL Express installed and running for this feature to work automagically.

If you don't want that to happen. You always create a database on your local SQL server install, run the [Aspnet_regsql.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx) against that database and create the asp.net membership tables there. All you would have to do after that is to change the web.config's connection string to point to the database that you just created.

Good luck, and hope this information helps you some.